# Is wait() needed after run() in boost process async child process?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-process

I am using `Boost Process` in async mode to get the `stdout`, `stderr` and return code of a shell command. In the code snippet below, is the call `c.wait()` required? According to `Boost Process 1.68` [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io) it is not required where as it is required according to [that](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_process/tutorial.html#boost_process.tutorial.async_io) of `boost process 1.65.1`.

```
std::string command = "ls";
boost::asio::io_service ios;
std::future<std::string> dataOut;
std::future<std::string> dataErr;
bp::child c(command, bp::std_in.close(), bp::std_out > dataOut, bp::std_err > dataErr, ios);
ios.run();
c.wait();
stdOut = dataOut.get();
stdErr = dataErr.get();
returnStatus = c.exit_code();
```

Now, I am using `Boost 1.68` and when I remove the call to `c.wait()`, I get a `returnStatus` of `127` instead of the expected `0`, which I get when I add the `c.wait()` call. What difference does the call `c.wait()` make?

Comment: The note about `wait()` not being necessary seems to conflict with the class documentation. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idp44365552-bb
I think the docs need some more work.

Comment: @RichardHodges, doesn't ios.run() wait for the process to exit? If yes, then why is c.wait() needed?

Comment: You would think that internally `waitpid()` has been called (perhaps even on a second service thread) but I have not spent time looking at the source code to check. Why not write a little MCVE to prove the documentation wrong and raise it as a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `run()` normally waits for async operations to complete.

However, you **could** have an alternative termination of `run()`

- when an exception emanates from a handler
- when another thread calls `stop()`
- when async signals alter program flow

In such cases it would be advisable to still use `wait()` so you avoid zombies. Other than that, the [`on_exit()` handler](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/process/on_exit.html) is the more flexible approach, in that it will allow you to multiplex several processes on the same `io_context`/`io_service` instance and still respond to child process completion as soon as possible.

Comment: I ran the above program many times on my Centos7 machine with and without the c.wait() call. In every single case, simple commands like 'ls', 'pwd', 'uname' have a c.exit_code() value of 127 without the c.wait() call, whereas it changes to 0 with a c.wait() call. So, it doesn't seem like normally run() waits for sync operations to complete.

Answer (score 0):

.wait will wait for signal from the child process and if already signaled meanning already finish the run, will assignee the correct exit code returned from the CMD, without waiting u will get 127 as you noticed.

[image: Wait function from boost]